# how to use emacs tramp with ssh remote to server

Tags: emacs, sftp, freebsd

I want use emacs remote server(freebsd use sftp with ssh). 
I already read [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) and write `(require 'tramp) (setq tramp-default-method "ssh")` in my .emacs. I use `C-c C-f RET /sftp:ganluo-home-vm-freebsd-user@192.168.1.104/`.
But it does not work

Comment: How about this related thread entitled **Emacs: How to view sftp folders**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546797/emacs-how-to-view-sftp-folders

Comment: byte-code: Unknown method "sftp"

Comment: /sftp:ganluo@192.168.244.129:/home/ganluo

Comment: I know I should use plink as a brige beacuse emacs use like I have be done cant conntin unlx/linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look Here:I use emacs for windows so can't direct use tramp.Have to download plink.exe(I use it maybe had other way) and do some other exp:

1. first download [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (also you can found some windows  conntion unix\linux software  in this website).Find plink.exe download it (offer release and development and source code)
2. than you can cut plink.exe in the your emacs\bin directory.
3. find your Environment Variables Edit/New "PATH" Add your emacs\bin complete directory and last the path must with ';'

> C:\Emacs\bin;
>
> then sign out use cmd test plink command is useful.if doesn't restart you PC.
>
> C-c C-f /pink:YouName@HOST[IP,HOSTName]:/
>
> it had some problem,I will post new status right here.

Comment: at 5 step you can use remote folders.